# Encrypt files on flash drive for easy decryption

Tags: encryption

I am looking to give some files to my accountant, who is not computer-savvy. I am going to put the files on a flash drive encrypted. I assume, accountant has no software other than standard Windows for decryption. I cannot rely on accountant being smart enough to download and install tools like truecrypt or 7-zip. I am also assuming accountant will be reluctant to run self-extracting executable, or at least I hope he is not that careless.

At this time, the best that option that comes to my mind will be to pack the files into a password protected zip file. This will, however divulge the file names, which I also want to hide, so I will have to zip the files twice - once into an non-encrypted archive, and second time into a secure one. I think there is a header encryption in newest zip format, but I could not find free tools that would do it (7-zip doesn't). Also I don't know if Windows is capable of decrypting such archive.

Can anybody think of a better option?

Comment: You will see from the answers so far that the core recommendation is that at least one of your assumptions is changed, either help the accountant install a tool, work with him to minimise risk of self decrypting archives or use an external web server.

Comment: for mac and Linux a possible solution might have been openssl which is pre-installed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files and https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/c7e85598664901afae03fedff308736b on a Windows machine openssl would have to be installed explicitly, eg from https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Answer (score 5):

Working at an accounting firm presently, we have that problem of needing to securely transmit files with no expectation of "smarts" by **any** of the parties involved.

We handle this by establishing (contracting out to a 3rd party) an SSL website that files are uploaded to. The client is sent an email with an authentication code (or we can suspend sending by email and provide the code over the phone, in person, etc). They get one shot to download the file. As soon as that code is used, the system deletes the file.

Comment: While I do not disagree with this approach being preferable over USB drives, the question is targeting flash drives as the asker's specific case.  So, this answer does not address the question.

Comment: +1 -- the OP is asking the wrong question. The real question is "How can I give files to my non-computer-savvy accountant?" The flash drive is a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the files in a TrueCrypt volume, and include a portable copy of TrueCrypt on the drive.  I'm pretty sure the portable version of TruecCypt could then be configured to automatically load your volume (prompting for password, of course) on execution.  I know TrueCrypt can also be configured to automatically open a file browser in the volume, once it's mounted.

Once all this is set up, just give the flash drive to your accountant.  Send him the password out-of-band.  Tell him to run TrueCrypt from the flash drive, using that password when prompted, and TrueCrypt will handle the rest.

Comment: Yes, but the question stated: “I am also assuming accountant will be reluctant to run self-extracting executable” (ok, that wouldn't be a *self-extracting* executable, but the issue is the same).

Comment: Well, absent a pre-established encryption tool of choice existing on both the sender's and recipient's systems, portable cryptography software is pretty much a necessity for this purpose.  Otherwise, we end up with an unsolvable problem.  There's got to be *some* software *somewhere* in the process, that both parties have access to, which can handle the encryption/decryption.

Comment: [You can put the software on a web server](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10405/encrypt-files-on-flash-drive-for-easy-decryption/10409#10409), for example.

Comment: @Gilles The asker here is specifically looking for a flash drive based solution.  Otherwise, I completely agree that a secure web delivery system may be preferable.

Comment: @Iszi, there _is_ a pre-established encryption tool, it's a zip built-in to the explorer since windows xp, which I already brought up as a possible solution. I am asking if anyone can think of a better one.

Comment: @galets To my knowledge, the built-in ZIP handler for Windows does not do encryption.  The only built-in encryption method for Windows XP is EFS, which is not meant to be portable between systems.

Answer (score 2):

7-zip can make a self extracting password protected zip with encrypted file names, you just need to set the correct settings.

- Set the archive format to 7z
- check the box for "Create SFX archive"
- Set a password
- Check the box for "Encrypt file names"

[image]

Comment: "I am also assuming accountant will be reluctant to run self-extracting executable, or at least I hope he is not that careless." -Original question.

Comment: @JeffFerland Sorry, did not see that line. but it does answer the question about 7zip encrypting header information. And if the accountant will not trust a self extracting exe you give him why would he trust something he would need to download and install/run off of the usb stick? If the accountant is willing you could put a portable version of 7zip on the drive, but why not just have it be self extracting if he is willing to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I believe it to be [AESCrypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/). It is less than 1MB, free, very easy to use and **won't get anybody confused about extra functionality (like 7zip)**. After installing AESEncrypt, you just have to Zip all files under one compressed file, right click on the file, select "AES Encrypt", select a password,

[image: Prompted for a password]

a new file with .aes extension is created which you can email to you accountant.

Your accountant opens the file by double clicking on the .aes file and will be prompted for the password.

[image: Password for decryption]

Comment: "I assume, accountant has no software other than standard Windows for decryption"